# Pass javascript variable through html code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, parameters, onclick

I have a JavaScript within which am dynamically creating an HTML form with a Confirm button. When clicking on the confirm button, certain JavaScript variables need to be passed to another JS method within the same file. But am getting an error in the code that I've written that doesn't adhere to the same js file but another jsp file, though it doesn't directly link or is affected by it in any way.

**JS Function with the Button onclick**

```
if (dropElem == "stream ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle") {
    var newAgent = $('<div>');
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(newAgent,connectorProperties);
    newAgent.attr('id', i).addClass('streamdrop');
    var elemType = "table";
    $("#container").addClass("disabledbutton");
    $("#toolbox").addClass("disabledbutton");

    $('#container').append(newAgent);

    $("#lot").append(

            "<h4>TABLE</h4></br>"+
            "<h5> Select a Table </h5></br>"+
            "<div class='col-md-12'>"+
                "<select id='attr-combobox-style' name='attr-combobox-style' class='form-control' id='tableListDropDownCombo'>"+
                    "<option value='Select an option'>Select an option</option>"
    );

    for(var q=0;q<StreamArray.length;q++)
    {
        $("#attr-combobox-style").append(
                  "<option value="+StreamArray[q][0]+">"+StreamArray[q][0]+"</option>"+                             
                "</select>"+
              "</div>"
         );
    }

    $("#lot").append(
            "<div class='form-group'></br>"+
                "<label class='col-md-12 control-label' for='tableFormConfirmButton'></label></br>"+
                "<label class='col-md-12 control-label' for='tableFormConfirmButton'></label></br>"+
                "<label class='col-md-12 control-label' for='tableFormConfirmButton'></label></br>"+
                "<label class='col-md-2 control-label' for='tableFormConfirmButton'></label>"+
                "&nbsp<button id='tableFormConfirmButton' name='tableFormConfirmButton' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='storeTableFormInfo("+newAgent+","+i+","+e+","+mouseTop+","+mouseLeft+","+elemType+")'>Confirm</button>"+
                "&nbsp&nbsp<button id='tableFormCancelButton' name='tableFormCancelButton' class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>"+
            "</div></br>"
    );

    $("property").show();
    $(".toolbox-titlex").show();
    $(".panel").show();

    i++;    //Increment the Element ID for the next dropped Element
    finalElementCount=i;
}
```

> Error on Console

[image: error]

Since I didn't make any changes to any other files, I'm guessing that the error caused here is due to the syntax line where I've tried to pass the multiple javascript variables(`newAgent`,`i`,`e`,`mouseTop`,`mouseLeft`,`elemType`) in the `onclick` function of the <kbd>Confirm button</kbd>.

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare javascript global variable and need to define first in script tag like below

```
<script type='text/javascript' > 
var myGlobalVariable = false; 
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/Other.js'></script>     
... 
<script type='text/javascript' > 
 // other java script code that depend on Other.js 
</script>
```

Comment: I have already declared a global variable within the same javascript file at the very beginning, but am still encountering the same error

Comment: Could you please dubug code and check that, variable with value is available on you file or not?

Comment: I checked and it is available as you've mentioned